# Input shape for a RNN in keras

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

My data set has the following shapes:

```
y_train.shape,y_val.shape
((265, 2), (10, 2))

x_train.shape, x_val.shape
((265, 4), (10, 4))
```

I'm trying to use a simple RNN model

```
model=models.Sequential([layers.SimpleRNN(20,input_shape=(None,4),return_sequences=True),
                         layers.SimpleRNN(20,return_sequences=True),
                         layers.SimpleRNN(2),
                        ])

model.compile(optimizer="Adam",
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
             metrics=["accuracy"])
```

[image]

The problem shows up when I fit the model to the data:

```
history=model.fit(x_train,y_train,
                 epochs=20,
                 validation_data=(x_val,y_val),
                 verbose=2)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_12 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 4)
```

I think it's something related to the input... but I don't understand what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing input should be 3D with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`.

`x_train` and `x_val` do not follow this rule. You can easily expand their dims by:

```
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis = -1) # (265, 4, 1)
x_val= np.expand_dims(x_val, axis = -1) # (10, 4, 1)
```

---

Another problem is `input_shape`. It needs to be `input_shape=(4,1)` according to the new shape of `x_train` and `x_val`. So the correct definition should be:

```
model=models.Sequential([layers.SimpleRNN(20,input_shape=(4,1),return_sequences=True),
                         layers.SimpleRNN(20,return_sequences=True),
                         layers.SimpleRNN(2),
                        ])
```

If you want to include `None` in `input_shape` then you should pass `batch_input_shape`.

```
model= tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20,batch_input_shape=(None, 4,1),
                                                      return_sequences=True),
                         tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20,return_sequences=True),
                         tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(2),
                        ])
```

This indicates any batch size is accepted by the model.

Note: If you specify `batch_input_shape`, like, `batch_input_shape=(32, 4,1)`, then it will throw an error if there is a remaining batch with size less than `32`.